# ¿Es posible hacer Computed Properties para un array de objetos?

Tags: vue.js

Es posible hacer algo como esto?, y como se haría?

HTML

```
<div id="example" v-for="item in items">
  a={{ item.a }}, b={{ item.b }}
</div>
```

JS

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data:{items: [
     {a: 1},
     {a: 3},
   ],
  },
  computed: {
    items.b: function () {
      return this.items.a + 1
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una solución es crear otro arreglo computado y usar ese otro arreglo como tu fuente para la vista. Algo así

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    items: [{
      a: 1
    }, {
      a: 3
    }, {
      a: 5
    }],
  },
  computed: {
    itemsComputados: function() {
      return this.items.map(function(i) {
        return {
          a: i.a,
          b: i.a + 1
        }
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" v-for="item in itemsComputados">
  a={{ item.a }}, b={{ item.b }}
</div>
```

En lugar de `v-for="ítems in items"` estoy usando `v-for="ítems in itemsComputados"` y de esta forma puedo acceder a los ítems individuales modificados en lugar de tu arreglo original.

Answer (score 0):

De esta manera te podra servir para hacer cambios solo a algunos elementos que necesites sin necesidad de sobre escribir los demas con los mismo datos

```
  var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#example',
      data: {
        items: [{
          a: 1
        }, {
          a: 3
        }, {
          a: 5
        }],
      },
      computed: {
        itemsComputados: function() {
          return this.items.map(function(i) {
             row=i
             row.b = i.a + 10
             return row
          });
        }
      }
    })



<script src="http://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="example" v-for="item in itemsComputados">
    a={{ item.a }}, b={{ item.b }}
</
```

div>

Comment: Hola Bartolo, bienvenido. Una consulta: ¿Tiene alguna diferencia con la respuesta ya publicada y aceptada hace 4 años? ¿Qué? ¿Qué es lo que aporta esta publicación? Cuando ya hay una respuesta aceptada hace tanto tiempo, conviene aclarar esto en tu respuesta... Hay que considerar que no tiene sentido agregar contenido duplicado