# Filtrar datos de dos arreglos en una misma propiedad computed de Vue

Tags: array, vue.js

Tengo un array en vue.js, el cual estoy filtrando sus datos a través de una propiedad computada. Esa parte funciona bien; sin embargo ahora quiero en la misma propiedad filtrar también los datos de otro array. Adjunto mi código. De antemano gracias, espero me puedan dar una idea.

```
data() {
   return {
       searchString:'',
       articles: [{
                'title': 'Cuaderno',
                },
                {
                'title': 'Lápiz',
                }],
      segundoArray: [{
                'content': 'text',
                }]
              }},
 computed: {
    filteredArticles: function () {
            var articles_array = this.articles,
            searchString = this.searchString;
            if(!searchString) {
                return articles_array;
            }

            searchString = searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

            articles_array = articles_array.filter(function(item) {
                if(item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1) {
                    return item;
                }
            });

            return articles_array;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: ¿Y donde piensas mostrar los datos? quiza te funcione algo asi? (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21895/es-posible-hacer-computed-properties-para-un-array-de-objetos) **¿Es posible hacer Computed Properties para un array de objetos?**

Comment: `<input type="text" v-model="searchString"/>
     <li v-for="article in filteredArticles" >{{article.title}}</li>
<li v-for="itemSegundoArray in filteredArticles" >{{item.content}}</li>`